# SSRS Excel Export - Detail Data Options

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report that is currently being rendered in Excel for the end user. The report is organized by month in the columns and sales group in the rows.  The data fields are the sum of transactions ($) for each month/sales group.

The end user would like the option to select a data field and have the underlying detail data open in a new excel tab (essentially how a standard pivot table would work in Excel).  The typical drill down and drill through reports are not ideal as there are hundreds of underlying transactions, thus the main report would be difficult to visualize. Is this functionality available in SSRS excel exports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to do this after the file has been exported?  If so, this is more of an excel question than an SSRS one.

Comment: Yes, this would be available after the file was exported. The report is currently setup on a DDS. So, I was hoping to build this option within SSRS to allow the end user to just point and click within Excel file to view the detail data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is "no, this functionality is not available". It's possible to have cells in report tables that contain a link to another report, these are exported to Excel as hyperlinks, but the link is to a report not another Excel worksheet.

It might be possible to to do something like this if you had a data region in the report for each possible drillthrough and then set these up so they exported to Excel as different worksheets in the same workbook. You might then be able to use the Go to Bookmark action to link to the workbooks (I haven't tested this). However this is unlikely to be a good solution as it sounds like you would have dozens of possible drillthrough datasets.

It sounds to me like a better option for you would be to build a SSAS cube of the data, your users could then connect directly to the data from Excel and use SSAS/Excel drillthrough and pivot functionality.